# How to plot these data in other way to better show the efficacy of my method?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot efficacy of my method over other prior models. The problem is my method is not that good to plot it in a normal way. Note that black is mine.
I would like to know what settings and plot type I should use to better illustrate goodness of my method.
For the sake of background, lets say there are 9 devices (X axis). 4 different methods are applied to boost them, the output is expressed in terms of efficacy(Y axis) . the highest eficacy means the lowest power loss.
The values are here:

```
A=[ 0.765   0.732   0.712   0.700   0.690   0.679   0.676   0.685   0.695]
B=[ 0.768   0.746   0.724   0.702   0.692   0.684   0.676   0.682   0.689]
C=[ 0.778   0.750   0.723   0.704   0.694   0.683   0.676   0.677   0.685]
D=[ 0.781   0.754   0.734   0.715   0.696   0.681   0.683   0.690   0.700]
```

Please give an example...
[image]

Comment: What are the axis supposed to represent? Have you done any statistical analysis to actually conclude that your method is most efficient? Can you provide the data you got so we can try stuff? Thanks

Comment: You just want to emphasize your method (the black line) ?

Comment: I edited the question and put the corresponding data. Thanks for checking @Benoit_11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to emphasize the line corresponding to your method you could to something like that:

[image]

```
figure; hold on;
plot(A,'.-','Color',[0,0.900,0.900],'MarkerSize',10)
plot(B,'.-','Color',[0,0.600,0.700],'MarkerSize',10)
plot(C,'.-','Color',[0,0.300,0.600],'MarkerSize',10)
plot(D,'.-','Color','r','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',2)
grid on;
legend('A','B','C','my method')
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort @matt  It looks like the same plot but with better settings and marker size. But I was trying to ask if I can use other plots like bar or ,.. or other statistic criteria to show my method is better.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would like to use a `radar plot`
[image]

This plot shows the performance of various machine-learning algorithms as the number of features is increased.

The 9 devices can be represented on the polygon. Different methods can be shown with different color. I'm not sure how you can do it in `MATLAB` but I'm pretty sure that it can be done in python, you just need to google it. Or if you are willing to then you can use *Microsoft Excel* or *LibreOffice Cal*c for this purpose.

**EDIT:**
Here it is. You can make radar plots in MATLAB too. See this link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33134-radar-plot/content/radarPlot.m

This is what I was able to make from your data
[image]
But I'm sure that you can get a better looking plot by tweaking the transparency and color scheme. It is clear from the graph that method D has the highest efficacy for all devices except Device 6 as you can see a green boundary in the plot for all the devices.

Answer (score 1):

You could try normalizing B,C, and D by A (I think A is the lowest line). That would turn the units on your Y axis into "x A" or you could also plot % of A. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Blue = A, Green = B, Red = C, Black = D]

The code:

```
A = A./A;
B = B./A;
C = C./A;
D = D./A;

figure(1)
plot(A);
hold on;
plot(B,'green');
plot(C,'red');
plot(D,'black');
```

Still I think if you really want to show your method or whatever is best you should do some stats. That's the most legit way to communicate comparisons between methods.

Comment: Thank you. This really looks better. But I am not sure if it make sense. What Stats can I use? However, anyone who gave a minus vote to this post should explain their reason and likely propose a better thing. @willpower2727

Comment: @Jamaisavenir To be honest, without knowing the background of your data my answer is basically a dirty trick to make your method appear awesome on a plot (perfect for presenting to people who are ignorant of stats or plotting in general). The idea is that "A" is sort of a baseline data set and you are showing the other data relative to "A." For example, it's like comparing how the batting average of B C and D compare to A. You'd see that for season 1, batter D is 1.022 times better than A.

Comment: Well, I will do that if thats the best choice. But for the sake of background, let say there are 9 devices (X axis). 4 different methods is applied to boost them, the output is expressed in terms of efficacy(Y axis) . the highest eficacy means the lowest power loss. (black) @willpower2727

Comment: @Jamaisavenir  for stats it kind of depends on how your data was collected, but in general you want to show that the means of the samples you got this data from are significantly different. If you're new to this concept try googling t-test

Comment: @Jamaisavenir ok I just saw your latest comment, for stats you could do ANOVA I think, maybe someone who is better at stats will chime in an correct me.